# Conditional Formatting in excel is not working as wished

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am using a true/false formula I want when the result is true the cell to turn green and when false the cell to turn red

I used this formula on the cell

`=$A1-$B1=$D1`

The results are displayed in column S

For conditional formatting I used two formulas for green:

`=$S1=TRUE`

And for red:

`=$S1=FALSE`

The results appeared as such:

[image: results of the above]

Could someone help me figure out how to make the formula turn the cell green when true and red when false?

Comment: Try this `=($A1-$B1)=$D1`

Comment: thank you! sadly this had the same result.

Comment: Can you show a sample data and the expected result. You can use [to create](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

Comment: The question is for which range your conditional formatting is defined. If you write `$S1`, your data needs to start at row 1.

Answer (score 1):

I've only created a sample of 4 cells, you'll need to adjust to your spec - but the following should work:

[image]

Open up Conditional Formatting Rules and check yours match the above.

If your range doesn't start on row 1, be sure to set the ***Formula*** to use the top-most cell and the ***Applies to*** accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the type of formatting from use a formula to determine which cells to format to only format cells that contain "TRUE" and accordingly "FALSE" respectfully to their colours and now it is working.

Comment: Please dont post any comment in the answer section, it is specifically meant for answer and not for questions or comments, if you find the solution posted worked for you and helped you to resolve, then please ensure to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it ✔️. It would be helpful if you go through this **[What Should I Do When Someone Answers My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**

Comment: Hi, this is the answer. I just commented what ended up working for me

Comment: can you clarify with an image what you did? did you do the thing that CLR suggested? or something different? I don't know much Excel so I can't tell. If you did something different than what CLR suggested than this answer can stay.